# Integration by parts - Divergence Theorem exercise

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Let be given the unit disc $S$ and the functions $f$ and $ \varphi$ on $S$:

$f(x,y) = (3x+e^y, e^x - y)$

$\varphi(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} * e^{x^2+y^2} \ \ \ \ (*) $

Now there is to compute: $ \int\limits_{ S} f * \nabla \varphi \ \ d S $

First one starts out verifying that in fact the divergence theorem can be used (also Fubini and the Transformation theorem at the appropriate positions), since the functions are all defined on a compact set, they have a continuous derivative and the set has a smooth boundary.

Integrating $(*)$ by parts gives:

$ \int\limits_{S} \varphi * div f  \ \ dS $ = $ \int\limits_{\partial S} f * \varphi \ \ d \partial S $ - $ \int\limits_{S} f * \nabla \varphi \ \ dS $
$ \Leftrightarrow  \int\limits_{S} f * \nabla \varphi \ \ dS =- \int\limits_{S} \varphi * div f  \ \ dS + \int\limits_{\partial S} f * \varphi \ \ d \partial S   $

However I don't see a good way to compute $ \int\limits_{\partial S} f * \varphi \ \ d \partial S $ , etc. Those terms look way too ugly to be useful.

Now I am wondering. Did I overlook something? Do I approach this problem from the wrong side straight into a dead end? If yes, what is a good approach?

Therefore I would be very happy about any sort of constructive hint, comment or answer.

Comment: First of all you have a wrong sign in front of $\int_S \varphi\,\operatorname{div}\mathbf{f}\,dS$, next the integral $\int_S \varphi \, dS$ becomes $2\pi\int_0^1 u^2 e^{u^2} du$, and the antiderivative do not evaluate to an elementary function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. First one was a typo, 2th was really careless of me. I looked the integral up on wolfram alpha and it looks nasty. So my idea above does not work well, dunno, if this problem is then solveable well.

Comment: I suppose the term $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ should not be there, in such a case all integrals could be carried out.

Comment: Or alternatively there should be $(x^2+y^2)$ without the square root.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked the case without the root. $x^3 * e^{x^2} $ can be integrated nicely. Then I can go back to my "initial" problem of computing $ \int\limits_{\partial S} f * \varphi \ \ d \partial S $, maybe something can be done there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested integral could be written as
$$
\int_{\partial S} \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{f}\,\varphi \, dl
$$
where 
$$
\mathbf{n} = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
$$
is the unit normal outgoing vector.
The integral on the boundary, using the parametric equation of the boundary
$ (x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ becomes
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos t,\sin t)\cdot(3\cos t+e^{\sin t},e^{\cos t}-\sin t)e^{1}dt = \\
= e\int_0^{2\pi} (3\cos^2 t+\cos t\,e^{\sin t}+\sin t\,e^{\cos t}-\sin^2 t)dt
$$
from now on you can easily procede.