# Integration by parts - Divergence Theorem exercise 2

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am still trying to wrap my head around the divergence theorem and to become better solving some integrals/problems.

As an example: Given is the 3 dimensional sphere S with radius r. And the functions:

$ F(x,y,z) = (x-y^2z, \cos(xz) - y, e^{x+y} +2z)$

$ \varphi(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} e^{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Now I would like to compute the individual integrals in this equation:

$ \int_S \varphi \ div F \ dS = \int_{\partial S} \varphi  F \ d\partial S - \int_S F \ \nabla h \ dS $

Computing the first integral is easy as $div \ F = 1-1+2= 2 $ and

$ \int_S \varphi(x,y,z) \ dS =
\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r} k*e^{k^2} * k^2 \sin(\theta) dk  \theta d\rho = e^{r^2} (r^2-1) +1 $

However now I become stuck and would be very happy, if someone could give me a constructive hint, comment or answer on dealing with the other two integrals (keeping in mind that I have just started thinking about parameterization, multivariable integrals and might still do many mistakes) - as always thanks in advance.

Computing $ \int_{\partial S} \varphi  F \ d\partial S $ might yet be the easier one left of the two.

First I would set up a unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ for $F$ with: $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} )$ giving me:
 $ (x,y,z) = (\cos(\theta) \sin(\rho), \sin(\theta) \sin(\rho), \cos(\rho)) $

then I could put the pieces together: $ \int_{\partial S} \mathbf{n} F \ \varphi \ d\theta d\rho  $

However now plugging in the functions for $ F, \varphi $ and computing the dot product of $ \mathbf{n} F$ does by no means seem nice.

Related question: [Integration by parts - Divergence Theorem exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603591/integration-by-parts-divergence-theorem-exercise)

Comment: Are you sure that there is the term $\cos(x^2z)$ ? Besides, what is $\partial S$ ? Does the sphere have any boundary ?

Comment: $ \partial S$ refers to the surface of S. Since S, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3 $is a 3-dimensional sphere, $ \partial S$ is a subset of $ \mathbb{R}^2$ and can be fully paramterized by: $\partial S = \{(r*\cos(\theta) \sin(\rho),r* \sin(\theta) \sin(\rho),r* \cos(\rho)), r \ const., \rho \in [0,\pi], \theta \in [0, \pi) \} $ 
Is there a problem with the term:  $cos(x^2z) $ ? If there should be one, you may replace it. My goal is just to become better at evaluating these integrals.

Comment: Ok : to me $S$ should be $B_0(r)$ (the ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$) and then $\partial B_0(r)=S_0(r)=S$. But nevermind, the problem is indeed the cosine term, which seems to be very difficult to integrate!

Comment: How would you change the term (to make the problem more solveable)? I suggest $\cos(xz), z \cos(x) $

Comment: Even $\cos(x)$ can be problematic, because $x=r\cos\theta\sin\rho$, so you will have $\cos\left(\cos\ldots\right)$ which is not very sympathetic. An easy one would be $xz$ (remove the cosine), and you will be sure to be able to integrate it.